# Android MediaPlayer and VideoView ANR(application not responding) when working with live video stream

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

Have been facing an issue with Android's VideoView and MediaPlayer when using a live video stream for the past few days. All other non live network videos have been working perfecting fine for many years now.

Cannot move to Exoplayer since lot of our users are on API versions 14 and 15. The ANR always occurs in the native _reset method. The following is a snippet from the trace file.

Is there a different way to reset the mediaPlayer when dealing with live streams ?

`"main" prio=5 tid=1 Native
  | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x7604f2b8 self=0x7f876c7a00
  | sysTid=10072 nice=-10 cgrp=default sched=0/0 handle=0x7f8c248a98
  | state=S schedstat=( 4827792381 564524901 5877 ) utm=400 stm=82 core=4 HZ=100
  | stack=0x7fc7a10000-0x7fc7a12000 stackSize=8MB
  | held mutexes=
  kernel: __switch_to+0x98/0xac
  kernel: 0xd565f18494f88f2d
  kernel: 0xd565f18494f8732d
  kernel: 0xd565f18495324be1
  kernel: 0xd565f184953203c9
  kernel: 0xd565f18495320791
  kernel: 0xd565f18495df17fd
  kernel: 0xd565f18495df1939
  kernel: 0xd565f18495f3fa41
  native: #00 pc 00000000000797d8  /system/lib64/libc.so (__ioctl+4)
  native: #01 pc 0000000000020a0c  /system/lib64/libc.so (ioctl+140)
  native: #02 pc 0000000000055e40  /system/lib64/libbinder.so (_ZN7android14IPCThreadState14talkWithDriverEb+256)
  native: #03 pc 0000000000056e04  /system/lib64/libbinder.so (_ZN7android14IPCThreadState15waitForResponseEPNS_6ParcelEPi+708)
  native: #04 pc 000000000004b6d4  /system/lib64/libbinder.so (_ZN7android8BpBinder8transactEjRKNS_6ParcelEPS1_j+72)
  native: #05 pc 000000000010aaa4  /system/lib64/libmedia.so (???)
  native: #06 pc 00000000000fa7a8  /system/lib64/libmedia.so (_ZN7android11MediaPlayer7reset_lEv+64)
  native: #07 pc 00000000000fa87c  /system/lib64/libmedia.so (_ZN7android11MediaPlayer5resetEv+64)
  native: #08 pc 0000000000049fcc  /system/lib64/libmedia_jni.so (???)
  native: #09 pc 000000000073ea30  /system/framework/arm64/boot-framework.oat (Java_android_media_MediaPlayer__1reset__+124)
  at android.media.MediaPlayer._reset(Native method)
  at android.media.MediaPlayer.reset(MediaPlayer.java:2048)`

Comment: Just out of curiosity, Have you tried call stop() before reset()?

Comment: Yeah, tried that.